# No index.php file in yii2 basic and yii migration error

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm a beginner and really struggling to get an existing yii2 project running on localhost.  As far as I can see, there's no index.php file, but all my online searches say that only happens with the advanced framework (I don't see any backend or frontend folders that come with the advanced framework in my project though?).

I've followed all the instructions in the project's readme file and it installed the vendor folder, but is giving me an exception when I type in the yii migrate command. It installed 13 of the 47 migrations without problem but then gets stuck on this:

*** applying m170317_154007_current_date

Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class m170317_154007_current_date does not exist'

in C:\xampp\htdocs\Duals\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:428

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
```

```
Stack Trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Duals\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(428): ReflectionClass->__construct('m170317_154007_...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Duals\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(364): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('m170317_154007_...')
```

So basically a two part question

1. This is all existing code from a working site, how do I fix this?
2. Will this create the index.php file at the end, and if not, am I just missing something simple as a beginner or is the installation just really complicated sometimes?

Comment: You should ask author of this app - this is probably custom solution, no one will be able to answer your questions without access to source code. But basic template should already contain `index.php` file. Advanced template has `init` script which will generate this file. I highly doubt that migration will create it (at least is should not - it is not migration job).

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I don't think it's been worked on for over a year, so I don't know where the author is.  There are a few files like example-index.php and just to experiment I tried using that as index.php, but that didn't work either.  Would this failed migration break the site like that?  Also, the instructions said to create a database and there's an extremely good chance I didn't do that right.  Would that cause the migration not to work?